# Cannot load routes.yaml configuration from bundle with Loader or Fileloader

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection, bundle, symfony4, loader

I got loader class to load routes config from my bundle - used both FileLoader and Loader

```
class InveoczAdminCatalogLoader extends FileLoader
{
    public function load($resource, $type = null)
    {
        $routeCollection = new RouteCollection();
//        $resource = '@Inveocz/AdminCatalog/Resources/config/routes.yaml';
//        $type = 'yaml';
        $importedRoutes = $this->import($resource,$type);
        $routeCollection->addCollection($importedRoutes);
        return $routeCollection;
    }
    public function supports($resource, $type = null)
    {
        // TODO: Implement supports() method.
    }
}
```

I have created this loader instance inside my extension class

```
$routeLoader = new InveoczAdminCatalogLoader(new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));//or with empty parameter when using Loader not FileLoader
$routeLoader->load(dirname(__DIR__) . '/Resources/config/routes.yaml','yaml');
```

I got exception that "Resources cannot be loaded from path that I exactly wants" It fails on Loader->resolve()
It's Symfony 4.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I have tried to check if bundle is registered and It is and extension class which created instance is called tried different loader and different file extensions and configs, but apart from that nothing. Service configurations are injected well.

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it, and add your debugging attempts around the file paths. For example, I don't get why you add some path to your file locator **and** define another path prefix for the `load`method